# How to git clone into a folder?

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, apache2, git

I have set up ssh keys correctly for the `ubuntu` user, as I can `git clone` if I use `sudo` to `chmod 777` a directory.

Obviously `777` is not a good idea, it was just to see where the issue lies.

So, in my `/var/www` folder I have my website: `/var/www/example.com`. I am trying to `git clone` into here but I get permission denied.

This folder is owned by `www-data` `drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data 4096`.

I have added my user: `ubuntu` to the `www-data` group.

I have logged out and logged back in again to ensure the permissions are set against the `ubuntu` user.

I still get permission denied.

How on earth can I make this work, I've wasted a day on it?

Comment: The folder is not owned by the `ubuntu` user. You are going to have to add the `ubuntu` user to the `www-data` group and change the group permissions. You could try something like `sudo chmod g+rw /var/www/example.com`

Comment: @AlexLowe "You are going to have to add the ubuntu user to the www-data group" I have done this already. Could you explain what this does: sudo chmod g+rw /var/www/example.com

Comment: Why don't you clone it into your home directory and then use `sudo mv` to move it over?  You have your permissions incorrect and `git` is overcomplicating it for you because it's adding an extra layer to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Ray 1. How would I do this? 2. Wouldnt you then have issues every time you wanted to git pull?

Comment: Yes to (2).  But by doing this, you're going to be able to figure out what you're doing wrong with the permissions.  And when you've figured that out, then you can get `git` working.  (Quite frankly, I'm not sure why you would clone from a repository that is directly visible to users via Apache...but then again, perhaps you have a very specific use-case that I just can't see.)